# How to monitor ECS Task Cycling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs

As the question states, is there any way to monitor when ECS is constantly registering and deregistering instances due to some error causing my instances to crash? I would love to be able to create an alarm or something that notifies me if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to put comment, so here are some thoughts.

1. I would run ECS cluster EC2 instances under an Auto-Scaling Group and based on ASG CloudWatch metrics, setup a SNS notification when instances are being added/removed.
2. We can have AWS ecs-agent docker container logs also sent to CloudWatch and get some SNS notifications based on errors or filtered events.
3. We can have subscription to CW from ECS as well when each service tasks being started/stopped.
   References - 
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch_event_stream.html
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet.html

Example event entries are in below link – 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html

Reference for setting alarm based on custom metrics.

https://medium.com/@martatatiana/insufficient-data-cloudwatch-alarm-based-on-custom-metric-filter-4e41c1f82050

Please do let me know your thoughts as well :).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example for AWS Fargate

Create an AWS EventBridge Rule which will trigger when there is a State Change for anything other than exit code 0
Use the below JSON to create an AWS EventBridge Rule

```json
{
  "detail-type": ["ECS Task State Change"],
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail": {
    "clusterArn": ["arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxx:cluster/xxxxxxxx"],
    "stoppedReason": [{
      "anything-but": ["Essential container in task exited with code 0"]
    }],
    "lastStatus": ["STOPPED"]
  }
}
```

Adding Cluster and Service Details is Optional

Alternatively, You can use the exit code to trigger the AWS EventBridge Rule if you are targeting a specific exit code

```json
{
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
    "containers": {
      "exitCode": [
        137
      ]
    }
  }
}
```